# Responsive web template for mobile

Tags: css, html, mobile, responsive-design

I'm working on the development of a responsive website.
It seems to work just fine when I'm re-sizing the window on my desktop, but when I'm opening the site from my phone it seems to thing I'm at a full size and doesn't show the smaller version.
Do I need special tags for mobile?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a meta tag for viewport? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: So short and easy. Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If u know about the Bootstrap then use bootstrap css to make your website fully responsive